# Inheriting all of template type functionality

Tags: c++

I am thinking of creating template class wrapper that is supposed to inherit all of template parameter functionality and add something on top of it. For structs and classes this would be pretty simple

```
class foo{ void bar(){} };

template<class T>
class baz : public T { void zab(){} };

int main(){
    baz<foo> a;
}
```

Now, my question is if there is any way to be able to keep operators for built-in integral types without tons of manual specializing template for those types to be able to do it like this:

```
int main(){
    baz<int> a;
    int b = a + 2;
}
```

Can it be done? If so, how? (I know it will be necessary to do it with some magic specialization. I am just asking if it is possible to do it with one partial specialization)

Comment: What do you expect the operators to do?

Comment: @Ayxan treat the class as if it was the template parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SFINAE friend class, you may reduce the specializations with template:

```
template <class T, typename Enabler = void>
class baz : public T { void zab(){} };

// specialization for integral type
template <class T>
class baz<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
{

    friend auto operator + (T lhs, T rhs) { /*..*/}
    operator T() const { return value; }
    // ...

    T value;
};
```